# How to run GnuWin32 sed and a script file?

Tags: sed

I'm running `GnuWin32` under `Windows 10`

I'm trying to run the following `sed` one-liner using the Gnu Bash shell:

```
sed -f <(sed -E 's_(.+)\t(.+)_s/\1/\2/g_' C:/dictionary.txt) C:/content.txt
```

The `file substitute sed` statement converts dictionary entries into sed expressions. The `main sed` uses them for the content replacements.

It is described in [How to awk to read a dictionary and replace words in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280675/how-to-awk-to-read-a-dictionary-and-replace-words-in-a-file)

`dictionary.txt` looks like this:

```
aluminium<tab>aluminum
analyse<tab>analyze
white spirit<tab>mineral spirits
stag night<tab>bachelor party
savoury<tab>savory
potato crisp<tab>potato chip
mashed potato<tab>mashed potatoes
```

`content.txt` looks like this:

```
The container of white spirit was made of aluminium.
We will use an aromatic method to analyse properties of white spirit.
No one drank white spirit at stag night.
Many people think that a potato crisp is savoury, but some would rather eat mashed potato.
...
more sentences
```

When running GnuWin32/sed in GnuBash-shell under windows 10, I receive the following error message:
`syntax error near unexpected token <(s`

**How to re-formulate the script to run under GnuWin32/sed under windows 10?**

---

with thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell and https://stackoverflow.com/users/5403468/tiw the solution works when using `cygwin64`

Comment: Maybe try putting all the stuff inside `<(...)` at the start and telling the main `sed` to read from `stdin` something like `sed -E ... dictionary | sed -f /dev/stdin content`

Comment: You could try replacing `-E` with `-r` You also appear to have dropped `/dev/stdin` - consider putting that back in or using `-` in its place.

Comment: thank you @Mark Setchell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to write the inner sed output to a temporary file first, use it, and then delete it:

```
sed -r "s_(.+)\t(.+)_s/\1/\2/g_" C:/dictionary.txt>tmp_script.sed
sed -f tmp_script.sed C:/content.txt
del tmp_script.sed
```

Another way, based on Mr. Mark Setchell's comment, plus little tweak, **with `cygwin` installed**,
this work on both bash and batch:

```
sed -r "s_(.+)\t(.+)_s/\1/\2/g_" C:/dictionary.txt | sed -f /dev/stdin C:/content.txt
```

Comment: @JayGray I changed it a bit, the temporary file way maybe working now. I'm not sure, but cygwin maybe still a good choice though. (You might need to remove GNUwin32 to avoid conflict)  I'm sorry that I misled you before.